# catch empty value within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

app demo http://plnkr.co/edit/r8kp9XyTZWok7hEusK1R?p=preview

I want to catch empty value of an object if it's empty.
says the 3rd name return '', but I want to replace something with it.

```
  $scope.user = [
    {'name':'Adam'},
    {'name':'Eve'},
    {'name':''},
    ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a value if there is no value like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in user"> 
    {{user.name || 'default text for no value'}}
</li>
```

Another option would be to use ng-show/ng-hide

```
<li ng-repeat="user in user"> 
    <span ng-show="user.name">{{user.name}}</span>
    <span ng-hide="user.name">default texxt for now value</span>
</li>
```

Comment: other than this method? because this doesn't work in my case, I used filter.

Comment: I'm not sure what filtering has anything to do with showing data, but I updated my answer with another option, which shows/hides spans depending upon whether the user has a name.